# async handling in Go, unintuitive behavior with goroutines & context

Tags: go, asynchronous, server, goroutine

## Background

I am working on a server and decided to move away from traditional async processing for long running requests (pub/sub, etc.) by using goroutines and context. My idea was to take a request and kick off a goroutine with a new timeout context that will complete the processing regardless of if the initial request context is cancelled (i.e. user refreshes).

I had done this before on a single endpoint but wanted to make a generalized reusable wrapper this time that I could give a timeout and put an async chunk of code in (shown below is working code).

```golang
type ContextSplitter struct {
    InitialCtx context.Context
    Timeout    time.Duration
}

func NewContextSplitter(timeout time.Duration) *ContextSplitter {
    return &ContextSplitter{
        InitialCtx: context.Background(),
        Timeout:    timeout,
    }
}

func (c *ContextSplitter) Do(worker func(ctx context.Context) error) error {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    errs := make(chan error, 1)
    newCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), c.Timeout)

    defer cancel()

    wg.Add(1)

    // run the worker
    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer func() {
            if r := recover(); r != nil {
                // if the worker panics, send the panic error to the errs channel
                errs <- fmt.Errorf("worker panic: %v", r)
            }
        }()

        // call the worker function and send any returned errors to the errs channel
        errs <- worker(ctx)
    }(newCtx)

    // create a sync.Once object to ensure that the done channel is only closed once
    doneOnce := sync.Once{}
    done := make(chan bool, 1)

    // run a routine to listen for when the worker finishes executing
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        done <- true
        doneOnce.Do(func() {
            close(errs)
            close(done)
        })
    }()

    select {
    case <-c.InitialCtx.Done():
        // initial context cancelled, continue processing in background
        return c.InitialCtx.Err()
    case <-done:
        // continue
    }

    // collect any errors that occurred during execution and return them
    var err error
    for e := range errs {
        if e != nil {
            err = multierr.Append(err, e)
        }
    }

    return err
}
```

Which is used as so

```golang
err := NewContextSplitter(time.Minute*5).Do(func(newCtx context.Context) error {
    // do some long-running tasks, including propagating the newCtx
    obj, err := doStuff(newCtx, stuff)
}
```

## Question

I finally got it working but I am making this post because I am not completely sure why it works and am looking for some insight into the inner workings of golang, goroutines, & context.

The main fix ended up being the removal of initial (request) context from `NewContextSplitter()`, i.e. this

```golang
func NewContextSplitter(initialCtx context.Context, timeout time.Duration) *ContextSplitter {
    return &ContextSplitter{
        InitialCtx: initialCtx,
        Timeout:    timeout,
    }
}
```

to this

```golang
func NewContextSplitter(timeout time.Duration) *ContextSplitter {
    return &ContextSplitter{
        InitialCtx: context.Background(),
        Timeout:    timeout,
    }
}
```

Basically, the request context would get cancelled and any functions in my worker that took the new (timeout) context would fail with `ErrContextCancelled`. I am thinking that the initial context cancellation got propagated to my `Do(worker)` and the `defer cancel()` would get called, thereby cancelling my new timeout context. The strange thing is that the worker would not exit via the newCtx cancellation from the `defer`, but continue running with a bunk context and err out on `ErrContextCancelled`.

My main questions are:

- Why would passing `initialCtx` to `NewContextSplitter` allow for the propagation of cancelling that context to `Do(worker)`, since `Do()` does not take that context?
- Why does the worker continue processing with a cancelled context?
- Am I missing anything else / any suggestions?
- Is this a valid pattern for handling long running tasks?

Let me know if I can provide any more context (ha)

Comment: Is your goal is to run `doStuff` asynchronously with a timeout context, then use code like this https://go.dev/play/p/6F5W4jVhJ7C

Comment: @CeriseLimón yes, my code does that. My question is about the behavior of `context.Context` in this case, which seems unintuitive to me.

Comment: In method Do: `defer cancel()` cancels `newCtx` when `Do` returns.  `Do` returns out of the `select` when `InitialCtx` is canceled.   The code in the question is overly complex given the stated goal.

Comment: @CeriseLimón ah you're right that makes a ton of sense. I do think it is worthwhile to abstract away some complex code into this wrapper for reusability & cleanliness across a codebase but perhaps it is a bit much for a stack overflow post. Either way, thanks.

Comment: Eliminate the the code instead of making it reusable. Given stated goal, you need four lines of code: create context with timeout, defer cancel the context, call function with context, handle error returned from function.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a clean up function at the end.

```
err := NewContextSplitter(ctx, time.Second*30).Do(func() error {
        // a block of code that could be processed synchronously or async, preferably wrapped in Atomic()
        // set object to completed state
    }), func() error {
        // a block of code to run if the context is cancelled
        // set object to failed state
})
```